# BSOD upon booting XP Pro x86 after dual partition install of XP Pro x86 and W7 Pro x64

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

I was able to successfully install and boot into Windows XP Professional x86. I then installed Windows 7 Professional x64. After that, I attempted to boot back into XP and I got a BSOD. From my search on the net, I believe this occurs often, but all the possible solutions have failed so far.

One recommendation was to use the XP disc, boot into Recovery Console, and execute the following commands:
fixmbr
fixboot
bootcfg /rebuild

IIRC, the only one that was successful was fixmbr. Successful, as in it actually could be performed. Both of the others were unable to be performed.

EasyBCD displays the following

[image]

Is there anything abnormal according to those settings?

Any recommendations?

Comment: Did you change anything in the bios prior to installing W7 and after installing XP?

Comment: No. The only thing I changed in the BIOS was the HD (controller?) from SATA to IDE before I even began the partition task. I'm thinking it is something related to the boot loader or MBR, but I am not exceptionally acquainted with either (I only know of them, but I have not actually worked with those files before).

Comment: That is why you got the BSOD, changing this setting will cause that, you need to install both OS's with the same Sata bios setting, or revert the setting back to ide.

Comment: I installed both OS's with the IDE setting, and I also got the XP BSOD with the IDE setting still selected. Just now I tried to select the AHCI (?) and SATA and then boot each OS, but neither allow the OS's to boot. Before, I was at least booting into W7.

Comment: Oh, OK, you still cannot change it after installing XP, With W7 there is a workaround to get it to boot after changing it, but not XP. Not sure what went wrong in your case, I have done many dual boots by installing XP, then W7 without issue. All I can suggest is to start over, wipe the disk completely of all partitions before you start.

Comment: Maybe you have a written tutorial or know of one because this is like the third time I've done this. I'd like to think the fourth time will be a charm. The tutorials I see tend to be installing W7 on a HD with XP already installed. But, I'm doing fresh installs of both.

Comment: No I have not, its pretty straight forward, set bios to ide, Install XP first, boot from the XP cd, when setup loads and you see the partitions, delete all of them until you see one large unallocated space, then hit enter to install XP on that space, then you will get a screen where you can define the partition size, set the size you need for XP, this will leave the rest for W7 later on, continue installing XP and when you get to the desktop let it load all the way, then shut down.

Comment: Then Boot off of the W7 DVD and install 7 on the unallocated partition that was left over by XP install. Hopefully you can boot back into XP when done.

Comment: I also need to install Ubuntu, so I should leave some unallocated space for Ubuntu, correct? And, you didn't mention anything about switching back to SATA for the W7 install. So, should I also install that with the BIOS set to IDE?

Comment: Yes leave space for Ubuntu, yes leave it set to IDE from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need a windows environment, may I suggest that you just use windows xp mode to run the software that doesn't work on win 7?

If you do need the environment, you can very easily create an XP machine in [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) without having to dual boot.

Unless you have a specific need to dual boot that xp mode doesn't fill, virtualization is often the answer.

Comment: Yup, I need XP because I have to access the Recovery Console which is not possible in Virtual Machine/ Virtual Mode.

Comment: @user7625: Is it recovery console functionality that you have to work with or just a method to backtrack/restore previous state(s)? You can always use VM checkpoints.

Comment: Yeah, I need the Recovery Console for classwork, and I also like the idea of having XP on its own dedicated partition.

Answer (score 0):

It may be something with the Windows 7 bootloader, why don't you just use the Windows XP bootloader and modify it to have Windows 7 as first boot?